# Reference parent column in nested relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

## Problem

I've spent the last few hours looking for a solution for this and can't seem to find anything that works. I'm trying to load all `Routes` that have at least one assigned `Aircraft` that is **currently at the departure airport of the route**, like this:

```php
Route::has('availableAircraft');
```

The `availableAircraft` relationship on `Route` currently looks like this, with the issue stemming from not being able to find a way to inject the `Route` into the final `where` clause (see `ROUTE_ID_HERE`).

```php
// Route.php

/**
 * This returns all assigned aircraft that are not allocated to jobs and are at the departure airport of the route
 */

public function availableAircraft()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany(
      Aircraft::class, 'aircraft_route_assignments', 'route_id', 'aircraft_id')
      ->whereNull('current_job_id')
      ->where('current_airport_id', 'ROUTE_ID_HERE');
}
```

## Raw SQL

I can perform this query using raw SQL, but I can't find a way to replicate this in Eloquent:

```sql
select
    count(*) as aggregate
from
    `routes`
where (
          select
              count(*)
          from
              `aircraft`
                  inner join `aircraft_route_assignments` on `aircraft`.`id` = `aircraft_route_assignments`.`aircraft_id`
          where
                  `routes`.`id` = `aircraft_route_assignments`.`route_id`
            and `current_job_id` is null
            and `current_airport_id` = `routes`.`departure_airport_id`
      ) > 0
  and `routes`.`deleted_at` is null
```

The crucial part here is the final `and 'current_airport_id' = 'routes'.'departure_airport_id'`, which I can't seem to find a way to replicate in the query builder.

## What I've Tried

I've tried to manually specify the field, like in the SQL query as so, but the actual SQL generated by this uses '`routes`.`departure_airport_id`' as a literal string and so returns no results:

```php
// Route.php

/**
 * This returns all assigned aircraft that are not allocated to jobs and are at the departure airport of the route
 */

public function availableAircraft()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany(
      Aircraft::class, 'aircraft_route_assignments', 'route_id', 'aircraft_id')
      ->whereNull('current_job_id')
      ->where('current_airport_id', '`routes`.`departure_airport_id`');
}
```

Am I vastly over-thinking this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as your eloquent query:

```
Route::whereHas('availableAircraft', function (Builder $query) {
      $query->whereNull('current_job_id')
            ->whereRaw('current_airport_id = `routes`.`departure_airport_id`');
})->get();
```

And change your model to this:

```
public function availableAircraft()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany(
       Aircraft::class, 'aircraft_route_assignments', 'route_id', 'aircraft_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the SQL query formed still had `'routes'.'departure_airport_id'` hard-coded in. See here: https://ibb.co/8XBxHRC

Comment: Replacing the `where` in the subquery with `whereRaw` seemed to do the trick though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adapting Mahdi's answer to use `whereRaw` instead of `where` in the `whereHas` subquery. So the final Eloquent query looks like:

```php
Route::whereHas('availableAircraft', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->whereNull('current_job_id')
              ->whereRaw('current_airport_id = `routes`.`departure_airport_id`');
        })->get()
```